# Unexpected [ - works locally, but not on shared hosting

Tags: php, slim

I'm using Slim Framework, and have set-up a very simple API to retrieve data from a database. This works flawlessly on my local machine, OS X El Capitan.

But - when moving the files to a shared hosting environment, all the routes throw 500 errors, with this error specifically:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
>   vendor/nikic/fast-route/src/functions.php on line 12

Line 12 is:

```
function simpleDispatcher(callable $routeDefinitionCallback, array $options = []) {
```

I can't work out why it is throwing a parse error on this line, and why it works on my local but not on shared, both running a version of PHP 5.5. Does anybody have any ideas on why this could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an old PHP version in your server which doesn't properly support Slim router. You should upgrade to PHP 5.5 according to the [minimum requirements](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/installation.html) of slim framework. [] style arrays do not work in older versions of PHP, hence the error message.

Comment: either that or revise the code accordingly

Comment: Upgrading is definitely the way to go.  PHP 5.3 reached its end of life [almost two years ago](http://php.net/eol.php).  Even PHP 5.5 will reach its end of life on [10 July 2016](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the array declaration with the older style like this:

```
function simpleDispatcher(callable $routeDefinitionCallback, array $options = array()) {
```

And on all other occurrences in your code. Or if possible, just upgrade the PHP version that'll eventually support square brackets as array declaration syntax.